# How to get number of items in ListAdapter?

Tags: android, listadapter

Has anyone know proper way to retrieve number of items stored in ListAdapter? Here is dim one (it works):

```
int count = ((ArrayAdapter<Object>)getAdapter()).getCount();
```

Where **this** is an instance of complex view like GridView or ListView constructed with data from ListAdapter and `getAdapter()` returns ListAdapter.

Comment: I think that is the best way

Comment: But it looks like dirty C-like hack

Comment: Why are you looking for an alternate way?
Is this method not serving the requirement for you?

Comment: @Eu.Dr. This method is correct but I was eager to find more elegant way.

Comment: @ghoshak Why is this "less elegant"? Does it take more resources in terms of memory? Does it have some limitations?

Comment: @Eu.Dr. The call is complicated and verbose. It causes an additional time investment that needs to get a clear idea about what is doing on in your code.

Comment: @Eu.Dr. It, in a nutshell, isn't good code style.

Comment: @ghoshak I never posted an answer to your question. What I meant was why is int count = ((ArrayAdapter<Object>)getAdapter()).getCount();, "less elegant". Do you have a reason for this?

Comment: @Eu.Dr. Take a quiz below, please. What snippet do you favor to see in a code `int count = ((ArrayAdapter<Object>)getAdapter()).getCount();` or `int count = getAdapter().getCount();`?

Comment: Both serve the same purpose!

Comment: @ghoshak Do you know what does ((ArrayAdapter<Object>) do here? If yes, how does removing this makes it more elegant?

Comment: @Eu.Dr. In common narrowing conversion is unsafe. That's why first version possible (with explicit cast) makes the code with snippet placed above unsafe for arbitrary Adapter usage. The only reason why it gives me correct result is that my custom adapter is extended from `ArrayAdapter` but nothing more.

Comment: My friend @ghoshak, the above is an example of widening conversion because you are trying to cast to ArrayAdapter<**OBJECT**> and not narrowing conversion. Secondly, even if you use :((ArrayAdapter<Object>)getAdapter()).getCount() it is as effective as the variant without the cast, because:
1. Just used once(The object) 2. getCount() supports no polymorphism 3. widening conversion 4. Improved Compilers to handle such optimization (You are not programming a MicroController here :)

Comment: Eu.Dr. ArrayAdapter<**OBJECT**> isn't widening because the Java compiler make no difference for the same types with different generic parameters. This comes from type erasure (see Oracle explanation ["Erasure of Generic Types"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html). And that's why it makes a code unsafe in way of possibility of getting **ClassCastException**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys. The solution is even simpler (I have realized it after reading an answer above):

```
int count = getAdapter().getCount();
```

The reason is that **ListAdapter** interface the return of `getAdapter()` call is inhereted from **Adapter** interface which has declared `getCount()` method already.

Answer (score 0):

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> lv, View item, int position,   long id) 
    {
        ListView lView = (ListView) lv;
        Adapter adapter = (MyAdapter) lView.getAdapter();
        int i = adapter.getCount();
        System.out.println(i + ".....size..........");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not a solution. I have to get number of items in adapter inside view class that use it. But you are right it could ease `getCount()` access.